# Dynamically binding an observable to a input inside a foreach binding using knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following table in the view:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>

        <tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveFilters">
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: dynamicFilter(Filter), valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </thead>
</table>
```

Following is my view model:

```
var vm = {
Title: ko.observable(),
Excerpts: ko.observable(),
Content: ko.observable(),
dynamicFilter: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data.Filter == 'Title') {
        return self.Title();
    }
    else if (data.Filter == 'Excerpts') {
        return self.Excerpts();
    }
    else {
        return self.Content();
    }
} };
```

The `ActiveFilters` object has a property called `Filter` which has names of the filters i want to bind as input fields in the page. Based on the value of `Filter` I want bind an observable to the input dynamically as shown in the `dynamicFilter` function and use the observables to access the values entered by the user later on to filter the data in the grid. How can we achieve this in Knockout?

**EDIT**

I have one more question, my syntax of declaring the view model is correct?(still new to KO). Say if I have one function called `filterData` in the view model and I want to call that function in `dynamicFilter` function I am using the following syntax:

```
var vm = {
Title: ko.observable(),
Excerpts: ko.observable(),
Content: ko.observable(),
dynamicFilter: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data.Filter == 'Title') {
        return self.Title();
        vm.filterData();// is this correct?
    }
    else if (data.Filter == 'Excerpts') {
        return self.Excerpts();
    }
    else {
        return self.Content();
    }
},
filterData: function(){
 //TODO
} };
```

Is the above way of calling a function correct?

Comment: Is Filter going to change? Or does it keep its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Filter` is not going to change, you can directly return the observable in dynamicFilter instead of returning its value by removing the parenthesis:

```
var vm = {
Title: ko.observable(),
Excerpts: ko.observable(),
Content: ko.observable(),
dynamicFilter: function (data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data.Filter == 'Title') {
        return self.Title; //instead of return self.Title();
    }
    else if (data.Filter == 'Excerpts') {
        return self.Excerpts;  //instead of return self.Excerpts();
    }
    else {
        return self.Content;  //instead of return self.Content();
    }
} };
```

Another option, maybe more readable, is to use the if syntax:

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: ActiveFilters">
  <td>
    <!-- ko if: Filter == 'Title' -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Title, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Filter == 'Excerpts' -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Excerpts, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: Filter != 'Title' && Filter != 'Excerpts' -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Content, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', returnAction:$root.filterData" />
    <!-- /ko -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Looks like `self` and `vm` are being mixed in a strange way. would this work as intended? maybe dynamicFilter is supposed to be called with the `new` keyword, but then how would `Title` get attatched to `self`? (I apologize if I'm just being silly and it's just some syntax i haven't encountered before.)

Comment: Actually "self" is useless here, it should remain "this" but why not. "this" is the current object. You cannot use "vm" inside the function as it has not finished being created yet.

Comment: @GôTô Both options that you posted are working fine and the second options seems more viable but I have one more small question and I have edited my question, please answer that

Comment: @seadrag0n This was answered in the comment above. Use `this` instead

Comment: @GôTô one last question, if we have to call a function present inside the view model outside of the view model, then can we use `viewModelName.FunctionName()` if I declare my view model in the syntax I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @seadrag0n Use `this.filterData` inside, `vm.filterData` outside